# Disable dynamic memory allocation?

Tags: gcc, stm32, dynamic-memory-allocation

I'm trying to disable dynamic memory allocation altogether in a low-resource application.  I don't ever use malloc/free etc and as far as I can tell neither do any of my dependencies.

I've tried zero-ing out the heap in the linker file `LinkerScript.ld`:

```
_Min_Heap_Size = 0x000;  /* required amount of heap  */
```

But that does not seem to be a guarantee that no library function will try to call `malloc`.

**Is there a way to enforce that no dynamic memory allocation can take place and fail the build if so?**

There is NO operating system on this project (bare-metal, [STM32F302R8](https://www.st.com/en/evaluation-tools/nucleo-f302r8.html)) cross-compiled with `arm-none-eabi-gcc`.

Comment: On which *operating system* or, as the standard says, which *runtime environment* ?

Comment: You should at least **[edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55175265/edit) your question** to explain a lot more about your application? Is it hosted or freestanding? What C standard library, what operating system (if any) are you using? What is your application concretely doing? Why do you need to disable heap allocation? Without any such details, your question is **unclear**

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch the use of [tag:gcc] and [tag:stm32] tags strongly indicates a certain runtime environment which is strictly speaking freestanding, but lets the user have about as much hosted functionality as he wants.

Answer (score 4):

In the [most common gcc based Cortex-M toolchain](https://developer.arm.com/open-source/gnu-toolchain/gnu-rm/downloads), library functions are provided by the **newlib** C library. The newlib implementation of `malloc()` and friends allocate memory for the heap using the `_sbrk()` function, which has to be implemented by the user software.

If there is no `_sbrk()` in your application, then the build will fail at the linking. Find it and remove it.

You might also want to check out how to find out [why a symbol is referenced](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39858015/stm32-gcc-arm-none-eabi-gcc-links-printf-even-though-it-is-not-used), or [make the build fail when an arbitrary library function is referenced](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26905841/cause-link-to-fail-if-certain-symbol-is-referenced)

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to disable dynamic memory allocation altogether in a low-resource application.

This is unusual. In general people are *limiting* the dynamic memory used by their (hosted) application (and how to do that is a different question, often [operating system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system) specific). Why do you want to disable it *entirely* ? As explained below, dynamic memory is very likely to be used *internally* inside your [C standard library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_standard_library) implementation.

---

Read carefully the C11 standard [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) (or the C99 one).

There are basically two "modes" or two "dialects" of C: the hosted C language and the freestanding C language. The exact wording in the [§4 Conformance](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#4) of the standard is

> The two forms of conforming implementation are hosted and freestanding. A conforming hosted implementation shall accept any strictly conforming program. A conforming freestanding implementation shall accept any strictly conforming program in which the use of the features specified in the library clause (clause 7) is confined to the contents of the standard headers `<float.h>`, `<iso646.h>`, `<limits.h>`, `<stdalign.h>`, `<stdarg.h>`, `<stdbool.h>`, `<stddef.h>`, `<stdint.h>`, and `<stdnoreturn.h>`.

And `malloc` is defined (declared in `<stdlib.h>`) and should be available for *hosted* implementations and is usually not available in freestanding implementations (but that is implementation specific).

Apparently, you are using a freestanding implementation (since you don't have `malloc` that the standard requires from hosted implementations). GCC [has](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html) the [`-ffreestanding`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C-Dialect-Options.html#C-Dialect-Options) mode for that. You should use it. Then `<stdlib.h>` is not available, and your code cannot use the standard `malloc` in that mode (unless it explicitly *declares* `malloc`).

In a hosted implementation, you usually can *redefine* your `malloc` (provided it still has all the properties required by the standard). Then you might use something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8460584/841108) (an always failing, but still standard conforming, `malloc` implementation).

At last, if you use a GNU [binutils](https://sourceware.org/binutils/) linker, you can always fail the link if your object files contain any external reference to `malloc`. That is trivial to implement -by adding some specific recipe or rule- in your [`Makefile`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Makefile) (probably using `nm`), or if using any decent [build automation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Build_automation) tool (if your build automation don't permit such a check just before linking, switch to one that does: [`make`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/), [`ninja`](https://ninja-build.org/), [`omake`](http://projects.camlcity.org/projects/omake.html) and many others....).

If you want to detect any use of `malloc` at *compile* time in a *hosted* environment, you might write your own [GCC plugin](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Plugins.html) doing so (I feel that is overkill, but the choice is yours). Or (much more simple in practice) use some script (e.g. with [grep](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/grep.1.html)) detecting occurrences of the `malloc` or `calloc` word in your C source code.

Notice that in most hosted implementations, in practice standard functions like `fprintf`, `fopen`, `printf`, `fputc` (and many others) are internally -at least sometimes- using `malloc`. Concretely, if your program (above a hosted implementation) uses `fopen` it is very likely to indirectly use `malloc`, since inside a standard `FILE` there is generally some heap-allocated buffer that `fopen` is `malloc`-ing (and it usually gets `free`-d at `fclose` time).

> Is there a way to enforce that no dynamic memory allocation can take place and fail the build if so?

In practice, yes. Just add some script in your `Makefile` doing such a check. Either use `grep` on your source files, or use `nm` on your object files. But if you use the standard `fopen` (from `<stdio.h>`) in your code, it is usually doing some `malloc` internally.

Alternatively, define your own always failing `malloc` and `calloc` and trivial `free` (like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8460584/841108))

On many [operating systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system) (the one used by your application, if any), there is a way to limit the heap memory at runtime. Linux has [setrlimit(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setrlimit.2.html) with `RLIMIT_DATA`.

If you are using some [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software) or open-source [C standard library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_standard_library) implementation (in a hosted environment) such as GNU [glibc](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/) or [musl-libc](https://musl-libc.org/), you could study its source code and check that `fopen` uses heap memory.

Comment: > This is unusual. In general people are limiting the dynamic memory

in baremetal ebedded is very common to not use it entirely, there are a lot of reason like memory fragmentation, easier to control resource, and generally safer code. Analyzing map file is possible to estimate max stack usage and the rest of memory is all dedicated to data, with heap usage is much more complex